# Can I use the letter 'i'in small letter in the middle of a sentence?

Tags: grammar

Can I use the letter 'i'in small letter in the middle of a sentence? I have seen many places where people have used it. Please let me know whether 'I' should always be used in capital letter or not.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the duplicated? There should be a reference linked somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

'I' referring to oneself should always be capitalised. The standard of writing online is exceedingly variable, which is why you see ppl using 1337 and txt spek.

It doesn't make it grammatically correct. Please don't do it.